# Can someone please clarify be on the below explanation

Tags: sql-server

I have a Employee table with 5 records, And i am running the below script. the result of the script is returning a record with EmpID 2. at the same time record is getting deleted.
Is this is the right way?

```
begin transaction A
    select * from Employee where EmpID=2
    begin transaction B
        delete from Employee where EmpID=2
    commit transaction B
commit transaction A
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't need transaction b, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You may just use this:

```
DELETE
FROM    employee
WHERE   empId = 2
OUTPUT  DELETED.*
```

This will delete the record and output its contents in one statement, atomically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the row with `EmpID = 2`, so you can do some work on it and ensure that this doesn't get changed before your delete, use an update lock:

```
begin transaction A
    select * from Employee with (updlock) where EmpID=2
    delete from Employee where EmpID=2
commit transaction A
```

You could also use a transaction isolation level higher than `read committed`, preferably `serializable`.